# Ruby if/assign statement?

Tags: ruby

I have run to the following code and I have no idea what it does. Why do they use `=` to compare values or are they assigning values and checking if the value is true after being assigned?

```
     if value = (key rescue nil)
       ..
     end
```

Comment: The latter. They are assigning a value to `value` and then checking if it's truthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
value = key rescue nil

if value
  ..  
end
```

or

```
value = begin
  key
rescue
  nil
end

if value
  ..  
end
```

Remember `nil` and `false` are the only two objects that are `falsey` in ruby and since `value` here could be `nil`, that if statement could return `false`.